# Get this UIAlert working

Tags: ios

I am recieving an error on this line in my ViewControllerLogin.m file or anywhere a UIAlert shows up...

```
[UIAlertView error:@"Enter username and password over 4 chars each."];
```

The above code gives me an error in the issues editor: "no known class for method selector". I identified the method 'error' in another class in  Xcode. Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

UPDATE ViewControllerLogin.m (the UIViewAlets are at the bottom)

```
#import "ViewControllerLogin.h"
#import "UIAlertView+error.h"
#import "API.h"
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#define kSalt @"adlfu3489tyh2jnkLIUGI&%EV(&0982cbgrykxjnk8855"
@implementation ViewControllerLogin
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//focus on the username field / show keyboard
[fldUsername becomeFirstResponder];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"qwertygreen.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
self.title = @"play";
//changes the buttn color
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
-(IBAction)btnLoginRegisterTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
//form fields validation
if (fldUsername.text.length < 4 || fldPassword.text.length < 4)
{
    [UIAlertView error:@"Enter username and password over 4 chars each."];
    return;
}
//salt the password
NSString* saltedPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fldPassword.text, kSalt];
//prepare the hashed storage
NSString* hashedPassword = nil;
unsigned char hashedPasswordData[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
//hash the pass
NSData *data = [saltedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hashedPasswordData)) {
    hashedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashedPasswordData length:sizeof(hashedPasswordData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
} else {
    [UIAlertView error:@"Password can't be sent"];
    return;
}
//check whether it's a login or register
NSString* command = (sender.tag==1)?@"register":@"login";
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", fldUsername.text, @"username", hashedPassword, @"password", nil];
//make the call to the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //result returned
    NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue]>0) {
        [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //show message to the user
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[res objectForKey:@"username"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    } else {
        //error
        [UIAlertView error:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
    }
}];

}

@end
```

Comment: Post your `ViewControllerLogin.m` file. A single line of code does not really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import UIKit.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: nice. i put your line in UIAlertView+error.h and the errors for both .h and .m files disappeared thanks I wonder why #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> wasn't used in the app I got the source code from and why that app didn't receive any errors?

Comment: It's because `error:` is not an existing function of `UIAlertView`. Look at the documentation for it.

Comment: can you answer me this please: when creating a the UIAlertView.h and UIAlertView.m should it be a subclass of UIView or what??